# How to run any Keras layer as a single layer to understand its behaviour?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

In order to understand the implementation of any Keras layer (e.g. `Conv2DTranspose`), is there a way of running the layer as a standalone layer (with Tensorflow backend)?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to develop a simple single layer model.

```
keras_model = Sequential()
keras_model.add(Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), input_shape=(32, 32, 3), name='trans'))
keras_model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD())
keras_model.summary()
keras_model.save('model.h5')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the weights of each layer in keras and use it to initialize the weights of the new layer of the same type. Then use this new layer as a model and just do predict. If the layer is not the first, you have to recreate model with all the layers up until the wanted layer, initialize their weights with weights from the trained model and the rest is the same.

Comment: I guess, i am interested in only a model with single layer or only a layer that i can for independently.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but if there are 4 Conv layers in sequence, the 3rd one takes output from 2nd layer (feature map) as an input, not an image. How do you think you will create that feature map? Or what will you give to the layer as an input?

Comment: Reason i wrote, is there any approach into my question.

Comment: No, that's the whole point. That's why i wrote that comment with those questions... There is one thing to do but I wouldn't do that. If you're using Keras functional API then you can save a few outputs of the layer just before the desired layer and observe it. Then create a model with just one layer, the one you want to see and initialize it's weights with the weights from, the same layer from model and feed the outputed images from the previous layer that you saved and see what's going on. But you will not be able to see much because you won't understand what's going on in the layer before

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

```
image_t = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next() 
inputs = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
conv = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same')(inputs)
m = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=conv)
m.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')  # loss and optimizer do not matter really
m.summary()

with tf.Session() as sess:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   image = sess.run([image_t])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   out = m.predict(image)[0]
```

Comment: the tensorflow code for what i wrote in for keras in the below thread as an answer.